# Create fake/virtual DOM in/for web worker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, web-worker

Is there a way to create a fake DOM or some sort of Virtual DOM for/inside the web worker?

Like, so I can make a copy of the main DOM and sent it over to the web worker to reconstruct, do calculations(involving the DOM), and then send info back to the main thread for it to change stuff in the main DOM.

Comment: Not directly related, but somewhat related, https://surma.dev/things/when-workers/ (search for 'VDOM' on this page, it doesn't have any anchor links so I can't directly link to that section)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of that DOM for workers, and it sends the diff result to the main thread for processing:

https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom

This is the only implementation of a DOM-like API that I know of that does what you describe. Others, like virtual DOM libs, have a different API that is not identical to DOM APIs.

(Sorry mods, this is a link only example because I don't wish to copy the project over to here)